# How to get a specific text out from span class in Python (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following span class:

```
<span class="k-pager-info k-label">1 - 25 of 93995 items</span>
```

and its **Xpath** is
`//*[@id="registerGrid"]/div[3]/span`

I would like to get the number 93995 out.

I have tried the following:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("""//*[@id="registerGrid"]/div[3]/span""")).getText()`

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("""//*[@id="registerGrid"]/div[3]/span""")).getText()
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'
```

What shall I do then?

Comment: Please format the code

Comment: I hope that you are using selenium with python, please use proper syntax

Comment: I am using selenium with python... are they not proper syntax?

Comment: use `text` instead of `getText()` in python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax error: Use `driver.find_element` instead of `driver.findElement`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="registerGrid"]/div[3]/span')
text = element.text
```

[Refer selenium docs for locating the elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply... but when I added this with .getText(), I got error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="registerGrid"]/div[3]/span').getText()
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getText'

Answer (score 2):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="registerGrid"]/div[3]/span')
```

you made a mistake it will be find_element and text only not getText()

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="registerGrid"]/div[3]/span').text
```